# Infinite loading is not working properly in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript

I have this component in which I have implemented infinite loading, I am getting the data in the console from the apex and it is concatenated with the current data, but I dont know at the very end it is giving me an array[0] and it just failed to load any data in my component. I have checked each and every thing but dont know where I am missing.

```
    <template>
    <div class="slds-scrollable_y" onscroll={loadData}>
        <div class="slds-card slds-var-p-around_x-small">
            <template if:true={products.data}>
                <template if:true={products.data.length}>
                    <div class="content">
                        <template
                            for:each={products.data}
                            for:item="product">
                            <c-product-tile
                                key={product.Id}
                                product={product}
                                onselected={handleProductSelected}
                                class="slds-var-m-around_x-small">
                            </c-product-tile>
                        </template>
                    </div>
                <template if:false={products.data}>
                    <p>There are no products matching your criteria</p>
                </template>
            </template>
            </template>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
//Lightning message service for communication between components
import { publish, subscribe, MessageContext, APPLICATION_SCOPE } from 'lightning/messageService';
//Importing messageChannel files
import PRODUCTS_FILTERED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/ProductsFiltered__c';
import PRODUCT_SELECTED_MESSAGE from '@salesforce/messageChannel/ProductSelected__c';

import getProducts from '@salesforce/apex/PosProductController.getProducts';

export default class ProductTileList extends LightningElement {

    filters = {};
    subscription;
    rowLimit = 11;
    offset = 0;
    pageNumber = 1;
    
    @wire(MessageContext) messageContext;

    @wire(getProducts, { filters: '$filters', pageSize: '$rowLimit', pageNumber: '$pageNumber'  })
    products;

    connectedCallback() {
        // Subscribe to ProductsFiltered message
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            PRODUCTS_FILTERED_MESSAGE,
            (message) => this.handleFilterChange(message),
            { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
        );
    }
    handleFilterChange(message) {
        this.filters = { ...message.filters };
        console.log('Handle Filter Change');
        this.pageNumber = 1;
    }
    handleProductSelected(event) {
        publish(this.messageContext, PRODUCT_SELECTED_MESSAGE, {
            productId: event.detail
        });
    }
    loadData(){
        console.log('IN the load Data');
        this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
        const currentData = this.products.data;
        getProducts( {filters: this.filters, pageSize: this.rowLimit, pageNumber: this.pageNumber} )
            .then((data) => {
                console.log('Load data');
                    this.products.data = this.products.data.concat(data);
                    console.log(this.products.data);
                    console.log(this.products.data.length);
                }
            );
    }
}

    public with sharing class PosProductController {
    
    @AuraEnabled (cacheable=true)
    public static List<PriceBookEntry> getProducts(CustomWrapper filters, Integer pageSize, Integer pageNumber){
        String response ='Check this out';
        String key ='';
        system.debug('Checking the offset');
        //system.debug(pageSize);
        //system.debug(offSet);
        if (filters != null) {
            if (!String.isEmpty(filters.pricebookId)) {
                key = filters.pricebookId;
                system.debug('The key is');
                system.debug(key);
            }
        }
        Integer offset = (pageNumber - 1) * pageSize;
        List<PriceBookEntry> productList = new List<PricebookEntry>();
        productList = [SELECT Product2.Id, Product2.Name, Product2.Product_image__c,Product2.Picture_URL__c, UnitPrice FROM PriceBookEntry WHERE Pricebook2Id =: key ORDER BY Product2.Name LIMIT :pageSize OFFSET :offset];
        system.debug(productList);

        return productList;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

note that on change of the provisioned parameters passed to the wired method, wire method might fire multiple times, so the recommended way is to use the imperative call inside the `connectedCallback` as suggested by @arufian

---

You can't modify the wire method property i.e. `products` it is immutable, you need to use separate property to store all your data.

So change the wired attribute to the wired method and define a class-level attribute(`productsData`) to store the data table data.
productsData;

```
@wire(getProducts, { filters: '$filters', pageSize: '$rowLimit', pageNumber: '$pageNumber'  })
getProductsWired({ error, data }) {
if (error) {
    console.error("Error:",error);
} else if (data) {
    this.productsData = [...data];
}
```

Then in the `loadData` method, contact the result into the `productsData`.

```
laoadData(){
    console.log('IN the load Data');
    this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
    const currentData = this.products.data;
    getProducts( {filters: this.filters, pageSize: this.rowLimit, pageNumber: this.pageNumber} )
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Load data');
                if(this.productsData.length != 0){
                    this.productsData = this.productsData.concat(data);
                } else {
                    this.productsData = data;
                }
            }
        );
}
```

Also you need to change the HTML file to use `productsData` instead of `products.data`.

Comment: Should I need to change anything in HTML file, I have replace products to productsData but now when I am loading my component then it is showing nothing not even my component. My connected callback is not working as well

Comment: yes @HJohn you need to replace `{products.data}` with `{productsData}`

Comment: I have updated my answer @HJohn

Comment: I am still getting the issue then when I scroll then it is adding the data in the end, but it suddenly vanished and no data is shown. When I checked the console then I see that at the end I am getting an array[0]

Comment: @H John check the answer by @arufian you need to use the imperative call from connectedcallback

Comment: When I am applying the approach of @arufian then I am not getting any data in this.filters in connected call back function. So, it always gives my array[0]

Comment: cant we add any condition in your code, as I am getting all the products in that but at the end it is giving me an array[0] and the list suddenly gone. So, if we add a condition so that it should not take 0 in the component

Comment: Just added a small condition in your code @Rahul and it is working fine now, please check my updated answer

Comment: @HJohn yes that is correct. also you need to update another condition. that I have updated in my answer.

Comment: Thanks! update it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `getProducts` on `@wire` and `loadData` method, which is make  function invocation for `getProducts` method twice. I'll explain the reason below:

I see you are using dynamic variable set for `$filters` and the others, this kind of variable set will trigger `@wire(getProducts,...` to be executed if you assign new value into `this.filters`, `rowLimit` or `pageNumber`. Therefore if you call `loadData()` method it will automatically trigger `@wire(getProducts,...`, and you are calling `getProducts` inside `loadData`, which make it will called twice.

**Solution**

You don't need to define `@wire(getProducts,...` in order to get the data at initialization.

You can replace it with calling `getProducts` inside `connectedCallback`. This will make `getProducts` called only once before first render happen.

```js
connectedCallback() {
        // Subscribe to ProductsFiltered message
        this.subscription = subscribe(
            this.messageContext,
            PRODUCTS_FILTERED_MESSAGE,
            (message) => this.handleFilterChange(message),
            { scope: APPLICATION_SCOPE }
        );
        getProducts( {filters: this.filters, pageSize: this.rowLimit, pageNumber: this.pageNumber} )
            .then((data) => {
                 // process the data here
                }
            );
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    productsData;
    
    @wire(getProducts, { filters: '$filters', pageSize: '$rowLimit', pageNumber: '$pageNumber'  })
    getProductsWired({ error, data }) {
    if (error) {
        console.error("Error:",error);
    } else if (data) {
        if(data.length != 0){
                this.productsData = [...data];
            }
    }


    laoadData(){
    console.log('IN the load Data');
    this.pageNumber = this.pageNumber + 1;
    const currentData = this.products.data;
    getProducts( {filters: this.filters, pageSize: this.rowLimit, pageNumber: this.pageNumber} )
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Load data');
                if(this.productsData.length != 0){
                    this.productsData = this.productsData.concat(data);
                }
            }
        );
}
```